# hbrBackground in c++

Tags: c++, user-interface

[image]

I have created the above simple GUI in c++. I would like the static text control background to be same as the main window (which is white) or how can i make the main window background (hbrBackground) to be the same color as the background in the static text control?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the background of the static control by responding to [`WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787524.aspx).

You can change the background color of your window by responding to [`WM_ERASEBKGND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648055.aspx) and calling (for one possibility) [`FillRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162719.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I used the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC and set the background to transparent.